# Performance: How to select all ListView elements programmatically in efficient way?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

In my application I use the `ListView` container with quite a lot of data. In order to provide the possiblity of item management, I use the `MultipleChoiceMode` to let user choose several items and copy/delete them. 
I do it by setting the:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(listener);
```

Where `listener` implements a `AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener`.

Since it is a useful feature, I decided to add the possibility to select/deselect all list elements at once.

Currently it is done with following code (I simplified the code to show the main concept):

```
private void selectAll() {
    for(int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
        listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly this solution's performance is strictly item amount-dependent.

**Could you, please advise me how to do it better/more scallable?**

For, let's say 15000 elements, current solution is extremely laggy.

PS. I can't change the container type (e.g. to `RecyclerView`)... :(

Comment: I would like to know the answer too. The standard solution is already laggy on Android 4.1.2 Samsung Note N7000 with a list of 150 elements.

Comment: Is this question still active?

Comment: Yes, I would consider it still active.